# Calling jquery selector after Angular function not working (rendering issues?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, rendering

I'm having problems in several cases when attempting to update data / onscreen controls and then use these controls with jQuery, especially images. My present case is the following:

**button click ---> call angularJs function that creates div controls on the screen ---> angularJS function at the end call JS function ---> JS function call JQuery selectors for the created divs. 
The problem is that JQuery can't find the created divs.**

What is the best/indicate solution for this case? (not only for this case, but for the cases where we need to wait for the dom render complete)

Regards.

Comment: This sounds like it's not a good approach at all. It will be incredibly difficult to test and maintain.  Perhaps instead of giving the scenario theoretically, you could take one example and post the code.  This way folks can give you a specific answer and you can use it as a pattern for your other cases.  As the question is now, my advice is simply don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several cases that could apply depending on your implementation. First make sure jQuery doesn't override angularjs functionality or vice versa. Second angularjs makes any JavaScript code in script tags invalid. You have to include your JavaScript in your controllers. You can use debugging tools like Firebug to see what's going on. Posting some code here would also help a lot.